# Definition of :duplicate_extra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

In the Spree codebase, the class [ProductDuplicator](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/master/core/lib/spree/core/product_duplicator.rb) has a `duplicate` method:

```
def duplicate
  new_product = duplicate_product

  # don't dup the actual variants, just the characterising types
  new_product.option_types = product.option_types if product.has_variants?

  # allow site to do some customization
  new_product.send(:duplicate_extra, product) if new_product.respond_to?(:duplicate_extra)
  new_product.save!
  new_product
end
```

I am trying to figure out where `:duplicate_extra` is defined and how it works. The [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/spree_core/1.2.0/Spree%2FProduct%3Aduplicate) isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `duplicate_extra` method is not defined by default. The documentation says:

> define "duplicate_extra" for site-specific actions, eg for additional fields

It's telling you to define it on your own if you want more duplication logic, like duplicating additional fields.

This line of code along with the comment above it:

```
  # allow site to do some customization
  new_product.send(:duplicate_extra, product) if new_product.respond_to?(:duplicate_extra)
```

is clearly checking if the product responds to a method `duplicate_extra` which takes another product as an argument.

The `duplicate_extra` method should be defined as an instance method of `Product` (or if you are subclassing it, you could define it at the subclass) with one argument, like this:

```
class Product
  def duplicate_extra(original_product)
    # copy custom stuff from the original product to self
  end
end
```

You could also try asking on [Spree slack](http://slack.spreecommerce.org/) for more details.

Comment: Am I right to assume that such a method would be a Product class method?

Comment: Check the updated answer, it should be an instance method.